# Draw x = parable in QCustomplot

Tags: c++, qt, qcustomplot

If i try to draw an x = form parable I obtain a strange draw.
[what i see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Qa5A.png)

Searching in internet i didn't find anything, this is the code that I use to plot the graphic:

```
ui->graphic->addGraph();
    ui->graphic->setInteraction(QCP::iRangeDrag, true);
    ui->graphic->setInteraction(QCP::iRangeZoom, true);

    double temp;

    for (double i = -500; i < 500; i += 0.1) {
        if(parableFormPair.first) {
            xAxisValue.push_back(i);
            temp = aTerm * pow(i, 2) + bTerm * i + cTerm;
            yAxisValue.push_back(temp);
        }
        else {
            yAxisValue.push_back(i);
            temp = aTerm * pow(i, 2) + bTerm * i + cTerm;
            xAxisValue.push_back(temp);
        }
    }

    ui->graphic->graph(0)->setData(xAxisValue, yAxisValue);
    ui->graphic->xAxis->setLabel("x");
    ui->graphic->yAxis->setLabel("y");
    ui->graphic->xAxis->setRange(-15, 15);
    ui->graphic->yAxis->setRange(-15, 15);
    ui->graphic->replot();
```

ParableFormPait.first tell me if the parable is y = or x = (if is true y =)

Comment: `for (double i = -500; i < 500; i += 0.1)` -- This loop is broken.  1) Do not use `double` as loop variables.  2) `0.1` cannot be represented exactly as a floating point number, so for each iteration, the `i` value will accumulate an error.  If you know you are to loop `n` times, then rewrite the `for` loop using integers, not `double`, i.e. `for (int n = -5000; n < 5000; ++n) {double x = n / 10.;` and inside that loop, use `x`.  Whether that fixes the problem you are seeing, I don't know -- but the loop is broken, nonetheless.

Comment: And if this does fix your issue, then [here is the duplicate link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken).

Comment: this doesn't change anything

Comment: The first thing I would do is determine whether the problem lies in your logic or the UI. I'd recommend printing out a table of your x and y results, and examine them to see if they're what you think they should be.

Comment: As a matter of interest, what do you see with the "y=" form instead? Did you check that xAxisValue[] and yAxisValue[] were empty before you called this routine? Your picture does not correspond to your code because the x-axis scale shown is not what you have coded. BTW, it's a "parabola", "not a "parable". The former is a curve that was known to the ancients; the latter is a fable.